# Is it possible to create custom page like Mails, Calendar or People in Outlook Add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to create custom page like Mails, Calendar or People in Outlook add-ins?

[image]

Comment: Certainly.  Of course, no one said it would be easy.

Comment: Nope, that is not possible in OWA by using built-in mechanisms available for Office add-ins. You need to develop a separate browser extension to try implementing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create custom page like Mails, Calendar or People in Outlook add-ins?

In OWA it is not possible. Outlook web add-ins are designed to work only under the currently selected item(s). So, such deep customizations are not possible with Office web add-ins. But you may consider creating a web browser extension for doing your changes on the page loaded.

If you consider the desktop edition of Outlook, you can do that only with COM add-ins currently. For example, you may consider using `Solutions modules` in Outlook. Starting from Microsoft Outlook 2010, developers can navigate to folders that contain custom item types by using the Solutions module. The [Programming the Outlook 2010 Solutions Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee692173(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article introduces the `Solutions module`, provides examples of the problems that the `Solutions module` solves, and then walks through a sample add-in to illustrate how to implement the Solutions module.

Another approach is to customize the view using a low-level Windows API by sub-classing the Outlook windows and injecting your own form there. For example, consider using the [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php) as a possible ready-made alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.